# What does '300222061712Z' mean in openssl CA database?

Tags: openssl

What does '300222061712Z' mean in openssl CA database?

```
$ cat index.txt
V   300222061712Z       05  unknown /C=CN/ST=Beijing/O=Example/CN=client4/emailAddress=user01@example.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread on the OpenSSL users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/gMRbePiuwV0):

> The index.txt file is an ascii file consisting of 6 (not 4)
>   tab-separated fields.  Some of those fields may be empty and might
>   appear not to exist at all.
>
> The 6 fields are:
>
> 1. Entry type.  May be "V" (valid), "R" (revoked) or "E" (expired).
>      Note that an expired may have the type "V" because the type has
>      not been updated.  'openssl ca updatedb' does such an update.
> 2. Expiration datetime.
> 3. Revokation datetime.  This is set for any entry of the type "R".
> 4. Serial number.
> 5. File name of the certificate.  This doesn't seem to be used,
>      ever, so it's always "unknown".
> 6. Certificate subject name.

The [`openssl ca` manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-ca.html) describes the expiration date as being in the `YYMMDDHHMMSSZ` format.

So `300222061712z` says the certificate will expire at 2030-02-22 06:17:12 UTC.